# compare two datetime fields in apex

Tags: apex

Comparing two date time fields and if they are equal, greater, lesser than then i am doing some logic

```
 DateTime currentDate  = DateTime.Now();
 DateTime previousDate = currentDate.addDays(+0);
 // Set date times to dates
 currentDate = Datetime.Now();
 previousDate = previousDate.Date();
 System.debug('Current Date: ' + currentDate);
 System.debug('Previous Date: ' + previousDate);
 System.debug(previousDate  == currentDate);
```

how ever in the debug i am getting false...[image]
how to overcome this??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `.now()` reutrns a datetime, whereas `.date()` returns only the date part... Your logic doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: i am trying to compare two date time fields....and based on that  perform some logic

Comment: @Kiran Then use `previousDate = previousDate.Now();` because updating with `data()` will return only date component and hence time is `00:00:00`.

Comment: Maybe just `currentDate ==/</> previousDate`?

Comment: You can do this by converting the dates in timestamp then a simple comparison will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare Date-Times as Dates, just use prevStartDat.Date() and currStartDate.Date() to convert them to Date values. See the [date-time class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date) for more.

Comment: @Kiran, you can also up-vote so that other can find it useful.